# Why I cannot export vocabulary terms via Features?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, features

Ok, I've installed features, uuid, uuid_features.

According to docs vocab terms shouls be exported too when creating taxonomy feature.

So I run a command:

> drush fe my_feature taxonomy:tags

but every time inside feature there is no such thing like terms. Only vocabulary is exported. What I am doing wrong?

From code review I see that only hook_taxonomy_default_vocabularies is implemented.

Comment: Ok, I've found way: https://anthonythecoder.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/exporting-taxonomy-terms-in-drupal-7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the module [uuid_features](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features).

It is both possible to export individual terms by listing the ones you want or you can export all terms with the vocabulary:

1. Enable uuid_features
2. Go to admin/config/content/uuid_features
3. Check the boxes of the Vocabularies under "Exportable Taxonomy term bundles"

   - If you want to export all terms then check the "Auto detect uuid terms" option, so future additions / changes will be added.
4. - If you didn't select the "Auto detect uuid terms" option: Do a drush fc and you will see a new item "uuid_term", get the list of components and do a drush fe FEATURENAME uuid_term:THETERMSUUID1 uuid_term:THETERMSUUID2 (gets really long, hence the "Auto detect uuid terms" option)
   - If you selected the "Auto detect uuid terms" option: you just need to export the taxonomy so do a  drush fe FEATURENAME taxonomy:VOCABNAME

Sorry about the odd bulletted list, trying to represent two options in one list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to export taxonomy terms without any extra modules is with update_hook_N() in your .install file.

Here's the code I use:

```
/**
 * Insert terms for MYVOCAB vocabulary.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_7101() {
  $terms = array(
    'Term #1',
    'Term #2',
    'Term #3',
    '...',
  );
  // Check if term exists in vocabulary and add it if not.
  MYMODULE_safe_add_terms($terms, 'MYVOCAB');
}

/**
 * Helper function for adding terms to existing vocabularies.
 *
 * @param array $term_names
 * @param string $vocabulary_machine_name
 * @param int $weight
 */
function MYMODULE_safe_add_terms($term_names = array(), $vocabulary_machine_name = '', $weight = 100) {
  //  Make sure the vocabulary exists.  This won't apply all desired options
  //  (description, etc.) but that's okay.  Features will do that later.
  //  For now, we just need somewhere to stuff the terms.
  $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary_machine_name);

  // Load the vocabulary.
  // Check if field already exists and add it if not existing.
  if (is_object($vocab) && property_exists($vocab, 'vid') && $vocab->vid > 0) {
    //  Load each term.
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($term_names as $term_name) {
      $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocabulary_machine_name);
      // Check if term exists and if it doesn't exist create a new one.
      if (count($term) == 0) {
        $term = (object)array(
          'name' => $term_name,
          'vid' => $vocab->vid,
          'weight' => $weight + $i,
        );
        // Save new term.
        taxonomy_term_save($term);
        $i++;
      }
    }
    drush_log($i . ' terms added to ' . $vocabulary_machine_name . ' vocabulary', 'notice');
  }
  else {
    drush_log('Vocabulary "' . $vocabulary_machine_name . '"" not found', 'error');
  }
}
```

Comment: That will only work if you already have the module enabled, since hook_update_N isn't called on install. hook_install doesn't work, because the vocabularies haven't been created by the feature yet.

Comment: Of course. That's why you first need to have the vocabulary created (with features or manually).
Having this hook_update_N() (even if you have it in the module where your features exports are - for the vocabulary) is good because you would be calling "drush features-revert-all" and after that "drush updb" to get the updates in.

Comment: But the feature defining the vocabulary has to have been enabled before adding the hook_update with the terms. You can't enable a new feature module that will both define the vocabulary AND add the terms without creating the vocabulary as part of hook_install.